# Frequent AppCrashes on new Windows 11 Dell XPS15 Laptop

Tags: windows, crash

I've got 2 new domain joined Windows 11 PC's (Dell XPS15's) that are both having the same issues. All our other computers are slightly older, some running Windows 10, some running Windows 11.

We have app crashes that occur several times a day and they all seem to point to faulting module path: ntdll.dll. Usually several apps will all crash at the same time, eliminating any issue to do with a specific app.

The windows error reports do not seem to indicate anything else, I have attached one here. Would be glad of any steering in the right direction!

```
Version=1
EventType=APPCRASH
EventTime=133050193711322389
ReportType=2
Consent=1
UploadTime=133050193740629397
ReportStatus=268439552
ReportIdentifier=0d38c049-15c8-4b15-9145-419669bc14b2
IntegratorReportIdentifier=1ce0bc31-da2c-46ba-8954-e9b6162381f1
Wow64Host=34404
Wow64Guest=332
NsAppName=Hive.exe
OriginalFilename=Hive.exe
AppSessionGuid=0000565c-0005-0012-8759-652b43b0d801
TargetAppId=W:0006c68c3adeb6dcc11655c1840786889b3800000000!0000b9d00f55234e5ffc61316551ddb9b3f031bd2987!Hive.exe
TargetAppVer=2022//08//12:04:52:07!0!Hive.exe
BootId=4294967295
TargetAsId=23507
IsFatal=1
EtwNonCollectReason=4
Response.BucketId=dd5ead439e993d8e3c1996c706e3638f
Response.BucketTable=1
Response.LegacyBucketId=2024815289037972367
Response.type=4
Sig[0].Name=Application Name
Sig[0].Value=Hive.exe
Sig[1].Name=Application Version
Sig[1].Value=4.3.14.33
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp
Sig[2].Value=62f5dc77
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name
Sig[3].Value=ntdll.dll
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version
Sig[4].Value=10.0.22000.856
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp
Sig[5].Value=92321736
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code
Sig[6].Value=c0000005
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset
Sig[7].Value=0007713e
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version
DynamicSig[1].Value=10.0.22000.2.0.0.256.48
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID
DynamicSig[2].Value=3081
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1
DynamicSig[22].Value=e8ad
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2
DynamicSig[23].Value=e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3
DynamicSig[24].Value=e8ad
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4
DynamicSig[25].Value=e8adce1c2b9e7be834b4063ac3c53863
UI[2]=C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Catamac\Hive\Hive.exe
LoadedModule[0]=C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Catamac\Hive\Hive.exe
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.dll
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\System32\USER32.dll
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\System32\win32u.dll
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\System32\GDI32.dll
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ucrtbase_clr0400.dll
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\mscorlib\a403a0b75e95c07da2caa7f780446a62\mscorlib.ni.dll
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
LoadedModule[30]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\5ca0785520097e25c49d3277f062382a\System.ni.dll
LoadedModule[31]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\a2ef0e7ab46193c59eeb270d9b1149eb\System.Drawing.ni.dll
LoadedModule[32]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\2c28bc50bf5ea04bfd0fd5cdad488af6\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll
LoadedModule[33]=C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll
LoadedModule[34]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll
LoadedModule[35]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
LoadedModule[36]=C:\Windows\System32\SHCORE.dll
LoadedModule[37]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
LoadedModule[38]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll
LoadedModule[39]=C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
LoadedModule[40]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CRYPTBASE.dll
LoadedModule[41]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
LoadedModule[42]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\9afa91e6389f194b1fe8c958bcd39b49\System.Core.ni.dll
LoadedModule[43]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data\bec0ce008dec4dfc98377cdc3f4d4d77\System.Data.ni.dll
LoadedModule[44]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll
LoadedModule[45]=C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
LoadedModule[46]=C:\Windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
LoadedModule[47]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml\e613016955f1fbf42644a8d397dc50c3\System.Xml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[48]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xml.Linq\434c1f2250f96ceb656ec7a9a5fa84a6\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[49]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Configuration\5b90c6a8d249684ae7c77b4b5f878059\System.Configuration.ni.dll
LoadedModule[50]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
LoadedModule[51]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\srvcli.dll
LoadedModule[52]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
LoadedModule[53]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\netutils.dll
LoadedModule[54]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
LoadedModule[55]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
LoadedModule[56]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.gdiplus_6595b64144ccf1df_1.1.22000.675_none_1631a6712776d946\gdiplus.dll
LoadedModule[57]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DWrite.dll
LoadedModule[58]=C:\Windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
LoadedModule[59]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.ValueTuple\0e9560dfb50cebaec83daca4b6ac51bd\System.ValueTuple.ni.dll
LoadedModule[60]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Net.Http\31787456beb16fa5c31bdf4c220ea3a8\System.Net.Http.ni.dll
LoadedModule[61]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.ServiceModel\6ae0b03c427bd013064bfc1a6457a7e6\System.ServiceModel.ni.dll
LoadedModule[62]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Comp46f2b404#\0fdeb60f9de0e50316c4d7539a8557cf\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ni.dll
LoadedModule[63]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.22000.1_none_6ec7c6847ea94424\comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[64]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WindowsCodecs.dll
LoadedModule[65]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Management\d7710bef5fe75b81eebfa4b830f7799a\System.Management.ni.dll
LoadedModule[66]=C:\Windows\System32\clbcatq.dll
LoadedModule[67]=C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wmiutils.dll
LoadedModule[68]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll
LoadedModule[69]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\wminet_utils.dll
LoadedModule[70]=C:\Windows\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll
LoadedModule[71]=C:\Windows\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll
LoadedModule[72]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\amsi.dll
LoadedModule[73]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Accessibility\79ef5abbf004a2553042fa55d89604b2\Accessibility.ni.dll
LoadedModule[74]=C:\Windows\System32\TextShaping.dll
LoadedModule[75]=C:\Windows\System32\psapi.dll
LoadedModule[76]=C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.22000.120_none_e541a94fcce8ed6d\comctl32.dll
LoadedModule[77]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll
LoadedModule[78]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\atlthunk.dll
LoadedModule[79]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data.Linq\baa20557341b57e485877c61a71c13e9\System.Data.Linq.ni.dll
LoadedModule[80]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll
LoadedModule[81]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
LoadedModule[82]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
LoadedModule[83]=C:\Windows\system32\Oleacc.dll
LoadedModule[84]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sxs.dll
LoadedModule[85]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Transactions\1cf4ddd17cc1bd68db500139e534ec77\System.Transactions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[86]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
LoadedModule[87]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\3de3a7158b5202ec222a441cfeef9c60\System.EnterpriseServices.ni.dll
LoadedModule[88]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Ente96d83b35#\3de3a7158b5202ec222a441cfeef9c60\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[89]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll
LoadedModule[90]=C:\Windows\system32\security.dll
LoadedModule[91]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\SECUR32.DLL
LoadedModule[92]=C:\Windows\System32\schannel.dll
LoadedModule[93]=C:\Windows\System32\Kerberos.DLL
LoadedModule[94]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
LoadedModule[95]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSASN1.dll
LoadedModule[96]=C:\Windows\System32\msv1_0.DLL
LoadedModule[97]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NtlmShared.dll
LoadedModule[98]=C:\Windows\system32\ntdsapi.dll
LoadedModule[99]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DSPARSE.DLL
LoadedModule[100]=C:\Windows\system32\netapi32.dll
LoadedModule[101]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LOGONCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[102]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
LoadedModule[103]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
LoadedModule[104]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
LoadedModule[105]=C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
LoadedModule[106]=C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
LoadedModule[107]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
LoadedModule[108]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mskeyprotect.dll
LoadedModule[109]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\NTASN1.dll
LoadedModule[110]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ncrypt.dll
LoadedModule[111]=C:\Windows\system32\ncryptsslp.dll
LoadedModule[112]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt19c51595#\7ee0763f91cdf43de05d79583dc7bf16\System.Runtime.Caching.ni.dll
LoadedModule[113]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Numerics\85a8875619db54867e7b9a26c0e322e2\System.Numerics.ni.dll
LoadedModule[114]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.CSharp\6b3f172f86eb8128b2776afefd3386d6\Microsoft.CSharp.ni.dll
LoadedModule[115]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Dynamic\f7f95f16c0ffe2215cb9040ae1ccce8c\System.Dynamic.ni.dll
LoadedModule[116]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runteb92aa12#\4871cd35a71d52242fd9e52860f9fa1c\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll
LoadedModule[117]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data86569bbf#\a8cf958e569c9bfdd56396a3a501aceb\System.Data.OracleClient.ni.dll
LoadedModule[118]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data.OracleClient\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.OracleClient.dll
LoadedModule[119]=C:\Windows\system32\explorerframe.dll
LoadedModule[120]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
LoadedModule[121]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
LoadedModule[122]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINNSI.DLL
LoadedModule[123]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rasapi32.dll
LoadedModule[124]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\prxyqry.DLL
LoadedModule[125]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\rtutils.dll
LoadedModule[126]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\RASMAN.DLL
LoadedModule[127]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winhttp.dll
LoadedModule[128]=C:\Windows\system32\dataexchange.dll
LoadedModule[129]=C:\Windows\system32\twinapi.appcore.dll
LoadedModule[130]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\UIAutomationClient\4b05f9a1dc38a5546ff40257e7c089ca\UIAutomationClient.ni.dll
LoadedModule[131]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll
LoadedModule[132]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll
LoadedModule[133]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll
LoadedModule[134]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\directxdatabasehelper.dll
LoadedModule[135]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
LoadedModule[136]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll
LoadedModule[137]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\drvstore.dll
LoadedModule[138]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\devobj.dll
LoadedModule[139]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cfgmgr32.dll
LoadedModule[140]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\wldp.dll
LoadedModule[141]=C:\Windows\System32\WINTRUST.DLL
LoadedModule[142]=C:\Windows\System32\imagehlp.dll
LoadedModule[143]=C:\Windows\system32\nvspcap.dll
LoadedModule[144]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d2d1.dll
LoadedModule[145]=C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_542214e117901254\igd10um32xe.DLL
LoadedModule[146]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll
LoadedModule[147]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
LoadedModule[148]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\XmlLite.dll
LoadedModule[149]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\Cabinet.dll
LoadedModule[150]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\d3dcompiler_47.dll
LoadedModule[151]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\edputil.dll
LoadedModule[152]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VAULTCLI.dll
LoadedModule[153]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Web\cdf057d76da40fd0bba17a1aa3a895a9\System.Web.ni.dll
LoadedModule[154]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\WindowsBase\67a3198ed9e1ad83ff3d925c4617b76f\WindowsBase.ni.dll
LoadedModule[155]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrcompression.dll
LoadedModule[156]=C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll
LoadedModule[157]=C:\Windows\System32\WKSCLI.DLL
LoadedModule[158]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WININET.dll
LoadedModule[159]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MLANG.dll
LoadedModule[160]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll
LoadedModule[161]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll
LoadedModule[162]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\PresentationCore\2b6b976c5386892cae95f826fbe5d665\PresentationCore.ni.dll
LoadedModule[163]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\wpfgfx_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[164]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSVCP140_CLR0400.dll
LoadedModule[165]=C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF\PresentationNative_v0400.dll
LoadedModule[166]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Presentatio5ae0f00f#\71e9c71a3d284a2aef0cc3e4a2ea86d8\PresentationFramework.ni.dll
LoadedModule[167]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Xaml\addff19c95fb5cc5e09eecc586cdddf1\System.Xaml.ni.dll
LoadedModule[168]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
LoadedModule[169]=C:\Windows\System32\msvcp110_win.dll
LoadedModule[170]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\policymanager.dll
LoadedModule[171]=C:\Windows\System32\coml2.dll
LoadedModule[172]=C:\Windows\System32\wpnapps.dll
LoadedModule[173]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.ApplicationModel.dll
LoadedModule[174]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runtime\4aef17dddb80afea6336ad15af0c838c\System.Runtime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[175]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runtbff93e24#\bf10cfd14873e5551f21d07cac3549d0\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.ni.dll
LoadedModule[176]=C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Data7706cdc8#\7bb0837c95ab8944cd58590b6930cef6\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.ni.dll
LoadedModule[177]=C:\Windows\System32\comdlg32.dll
LoadedModule[178]=C:\Windows\System32\DUI70.dll
LoadedModule[179]=C:\Windows\System32\DUser.dll
LoadedModule[180]=C:\Windows\System32\thumbcache.dll
LoadedModule[181]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.FileExplorer.dll
LoadedModule[182]=C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
LoadedModule[183]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
LoadedModule[184]=C:\Windows\System32\p9np.dll
LoadedModule[185]=C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
LoadedModule[186]=C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
LoadedModule[187]=C:\Windows\System32\davclnt.dll
LoadedModule[188]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cscapi.dll
LoadedModule[189]=C:\Windows\System32\uiautomationcore.dll
LoadedModule[190]=C:\Windows\System32\StructuredQuery.dll
LoadedModule[191]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.FileExplorer.Common.dll
LoadedModule[192]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll
LoadedModule[193]=C:\Windows\system32\IconCodecService.dll
LoadedModule[194]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.System.Launcher.dll
LoadedModule[195]=C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
LoadedModule[196]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.staterepositorycore.dll
LoadedModule[197]=C:\Windows\System32\twinapi.dll
LoadedModule[198]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntshrui.dll
LoadedModule[199]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\windows.staterepositoryclient.dll
LoadedModule[200]=C:\Program Files\Microsoft OneDrive\22.151.0717.0001\i386\FileSyncShell.dll
LoadedModule[201]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WTSAPI32.dll
LoadedModule[202]=C:\Windows\System32\ActXPrxy.dll
LoadedModule[203]=C:\Windows\System32\dlnashext.dll
LoadedModule[204]=C:\Windows\System32\DevDispItemProvider.dll
LoadedModule[205]=C:\Windows\System32\DSROLE.dll
LoadedModule[206]=C:\Windows\System32\ACTIVEDS.dll
LoadedModule[207]=C:\Windows\System32\adsldpc.dll
LoadedModule[208]=C:\Windows\System32\WLDAP32.dll
LoadedModule[209]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\cryptdll.dll
LoadedModule[210]=C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
LoadedModule[211]=C:\Windows\System32\Windows.Shell.ServiceHostBuilder.dll
LoadedModule[212]=C:\Windows\System32\OneCoreUAPCommonProxyStub.dll
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1
State[0].Value=1
OsInfo[0].Key=vermaj
OsInfo[0].Value=10
OsInfo[1].Key=vermin
OsInfo[1].Value=0
OsInfo[2].Key=verbld
OsInfo[2].Value=22000
OsInfo[3].Key=ubr
OsInfo[3].Value=856
OsInfo[4].Key=versp
OsInfo[4].Value=0
OsInfo[5].Key=arch
OsInfo[5].Value=9
OsInfo[6].Key=lcid
OsInfo[6].Value=1033
OsInfo[7].Key=geoid
OsInfo[7].Value=12
OsInfo[8].Key=sku
OsInfo[8].Value=48
OsInfo[9].Key=domain
OsInfo[9].Value=1
OsInfo[10].Key=prodsuite
OsInfo[10].Value=256
OsInfo[11].Key=ntprodtype
OsInfo[11].Value=1
OsInfo[12].Key=platid
OsInfo[12].Value=10
OsInfo[13].Key=sr
OsInfo[13].Value=0
OsInfo[14].Key=tmsi
OsInfo[14].Value=221747556
OsInfo[15].Key=osinsty
OsInfo[15].Value=2
OsInfo[16].Key=iever
OsInfo[16].Value=11.1.22000.0-11.0.1000
OsInfo[17].Key=portos
OsInfo[17].Value=0
OsInfo[18].Key=ram
OsInfo[18].Value=16055
OsInfo[19].Key=svolsz
OsInfo[19].Value=457
OsInfo[20].Key=wimbt
OsInfo[20].Value=0
OsInfo[21].Key=blddt
OsInfo[21].Value=210604
OsInfo[22].Key=bldtm
OsInfo[22].Value=1628
OsInfo[23].Key=bldbrch
OsInfo[23].Value=co_release
OsInfo[24].Key=bldchk
OsInfo[24].Value=0
OsInfo[25].Key=wpvermaj
OsInfo[25].Value=0
OsInfo[26].Key=wpvermin
OsInfo[26].Value=0
OsInfo[27].Key=wpbuildmaj
OsInfo[27].Value=0
OsInfo[28].Key=wpbuildmin
OsInfo[28].Value=0
OsInfo[29].Key=osver
OsInfo[29].Value=10.0.22000.856.amd64fre.co_release.210604-1628
OsInfo[30].Key=buildflightid
OsInfo[31].Key=edition
OsInfo[31].Value=Professional
OsInfo[32].Key=ring
OsInfo[32].Value=Retail
OsInfo[33].Key=expid
OsInfo[34].Key=fconid
OsInfo[34].Value=23877894,1,2,0;25704915,1,2,1;35825666,0,1,1;37801696,0,1,1;37837060,0,1,1;37926348,0,1,0;38406949,0,1,1;38651681,0,1,1
OsInfo[35].Key=containerid
OsInfo[36].Key=containertype
OsInfo[37].Key=edu
OsInfo[37].Value=0
OsInfo[38].Key=servicinginprogress
OsInfo[38].Value=0
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working
ConsentKey=APPCRASH
AppName=Hive
AppPath=C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Catamac\Hive\Hive.exe
NsPartner=windows
NsGroup=windows8
ApplicationIdentity=BFC0CD2E4BADF4B9EBF30C9CA2142E95
MetadataHash=714071867
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Run the dism tool to repair your windows install.  You may also want to run sfc /scannow command, which has its own repair processes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/what-is-dism?view=windows-11